# mutate a new column with values from another column using the name of that column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
a <- data.frame("One" = c(1,2),
                "Two" = c(3,4),
                "Three" = c("One","Two"))
```

and I want to convert the Three column string values to the values in the One and Two column so that the output looks like this:

```
b <- data.frame("One" = c(1,2),
                "Two" = c(3,4),
                "Three" = c(1,4))
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
b<- a %>% mutate(
  Three = as.name(Three))
```

*** This is a simplified example. In my real data, I want to be able to use the string value to capture the value of another column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We could use `row_number()` in an `ifelse` statement

```
library(dplyr)
b %>%  
    mutate(Three = ifelse(row_number() == 1, One, Two))
```

Output:

```
  One Two Three
1   1   3     1
2   2   4     4
```